# excessing order object while sending a request to another server

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've encontered a problem while establishing a refund request...
when I run the code the woocommerce order object is not recognized and I can't excess the order id and payment amount. I tried to include a woocommerce file the define the order object but for some reason the code after that do not show in page or even in the console.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "./wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php";


global $woocommerce;

$w = 'https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/nonpci?wsdl';
$client = new \SoapClient($w);

$orderId = $_GET['order'];

$order = wc_get_order($orderId);

$BankReceiptID = $order->_BankReceiptID;

$propertys = [
  'DigitalKey'            => 'D7C700C4-92DD-0CA2-E043-0A1017ACD099',
  // 'PaymentID'             =>  $_GET['TransactionID'], // PaymentID  or BankReceiptID
  'BankReceiptID'         =>  $BankReceiptID, //PaymentID or BankReceiptID
  'RefundAmountInCents'   => (($order->get_total()*100)-1500), //total back
];

$RefundResult = $client->ProcessRefund($propertys);

echo '$RefundResult: ' . $RefundResult;
return; // remove after checking how to get the RefundResult letter

//print_r($client->ProcessRefund($propertys));

header('Location:http://localhost/360transformation/?page_id=567&order=' . $orderId . '&RefundResult=' . $RefundResult->ProccessRefundResult->Data->RefundResult);
```

Comment: how are you calling or running this code? ajax? or what?

Comment: calling this code. its in a php file that is called when you open this page. no ajax